# Remove data from array of array of elements

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am working on removing data from array of elements in array of elements in my mongoDb using mongoose but i am unable to do

my schema looks like this

```
    var schema = mongoose.Schema({
       name : String,
       surgeries :  [{
                    patient_name : String,
                    trays : [{
                           tray_id : { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'trays' },
                            removed_time : Date,
                            removed_by : { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'users' },
                    }],
                    traydata : Array,
                }]
 },{strict : false} );
```

i was trying to remove data from trays array

I have done 2 ways but it doesnt worked

1)i have used pull ans i have written query like this

```
   Ots.update({'surgeries.trays.tray_id':id},{ $pull: { 'surgeries.trays' : result[0] } }, {safe: true },function(err,obj){
                                console.log(obj);
                            })
```

its showing output like this

```
   { ok: 1, nModified: 0, n: 1 }
```

2)i have found the object by using ID and  I have find the index of that tray and splice that tray and i have saved that object it is working for one tray object when i am looping i was getting an error that version and object not found error

i have used { versionKey: false } in schema file its not showing error and when i was trying to remove multiple records its only removing the one object that is first

Thank you,
Babji

Comment: Maybe you should try { $pull: { 'surgeries': {'trays' : result[0] } } } or { $pull: { 'surgeries': {'trays' : { '$elemMatch': result[0] } } } }

Comment: i got that by using { $pull: { 'surgeries.$.trays' : result[0] } }

Answer (score 0):

`nModified:0` indicates that nothing is being updated when you perform `Ots.update`.

What data are you trying to remove in the trays array?

If you were trying to remove a tray with a certain `id` you should try the following:

`Ots.update({'surguries'},{$pull:{trays: {tray_id: theTrayYouWantToRemove}}})`